# smoke alarm interconnecct signal voltage

Tags: electrical, wiring

Only a question for my information.  For hardwired battery backup smoke alarms.  If they are not house powered obviously the interconnect signal is 9V.  When they are house powered is the interconnect signal still 9V from the installed batteries or is it the AC equivalent supplied by the house voltage.

Comment: Would imagine it would use house current to save the battery, but do not know if it is full house current/voltage.  Interesting question.

Comment: Chuck, great question.  I've wondered this myself before since they just magically work and the home builder wired them in at once.